# How can I run a Virtual Machine in a Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine

My system is a Microsoft Windows 7 running on VMare, now I need run VMware Player to run another Virtual Machine in Windows 7(by opeing .vmdk file). However, I meet an error which shows:

[image: Error message]

Does any know what should I do to run this VM in my VM?

Comment: It's telling you what to do in the error message.

Comment: I once tried to run MVS 3.8J inside Hercules inside Linux inside VMWare on Windows. It _ran,_ but not as fast as I'd hoped. So this _may_ not be the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although for many reasons you'd be better to run this child vm as a sibling VM on the physical host (instead of inside your Windows 7 VM), if you wanted to you need to edit the .vmx files for the Windows 7 VM, assuming you have access.

**NOTE**: Your child VM will not run well and VMware Tools will not work. This is an experimental configuration and not advised for long term use.

Add the following lines to the .VMX file of your VM:

> isolation.tools.getPtrLocation.disable = “TRUE”
>
> isolation.tools.setPtrLocation.disable = “TRUE”
>
> isolation.tools.setVersion.disable = “TRUE”
>
> isolation.tools.getVersion.disable = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_directexec = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_chksimd = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_ntreloc = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_selfmod = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_reloc = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_btinout = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_btmemspace = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_btpriv = “TRUE”
>
> monitor_control.disable_btseg = “TRUE”

Also, ensure you change the VMware tools upgrade policy so it doesn't try to fix the VMware tools not functioning.

> tools.upgrade.policy = “manual”

Then start the Windows 7 VM and you shoul.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an illustrated guide: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/installation-and-deployment/install-vmware-esx-server-guest-operating-system.html

Comment: This guide is show us how to install VMware ESX Server Guest Operating System, but now my problem is can't run Vmare inside a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases ,you just need to delete or modify all you regedits contaning the string "vmware" or "vbox" . Press "Ctrl +R" ,type "regedit",open it up, then press "Ctrl +F" to search "vbox" or "vmware" and delete or modify all you searched results.Especially these:

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/DSDT/VBOX_"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/DSDT/VBOX_/VBOXBIOS"

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/FADT/VBOX_/"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/FADT/VBOX_/VBOXFACP"

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/RSDT/VBOX_/"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/RSDT/VBOX_/VBOXXSDT"

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/DESCRIPTION/"

I'm using "VBOX" because it was a virtualbox virtual machine ,you need to change it to "vmware" if you are using vmware.

Whether you'll have to use this technique depends on which method the software you are trying to open uses to verify if you are in a VM.If it searches all your regedits to detect the strings ,this method I wrote above works.Otherwise you still net to find out oter work arounds.